# What meta data shares my Linux via Wifi?

Tags: wifi, privacy

Is there a way to find out what kind of data my Linux shares with a wifi host? Like, he'll probably know my (wifi interface) MAC address, IP address, hostname. But what about other information like hardware information, operating system version, etc. Is that shared as well? Can I configure that somehow? Is there a standard/RFC to read about such kind of meta data?

Comment: If you connect to a hotspot you control, e.g. an OpenWRT router, you can see a lot of this. Short version: mostly just stuff immediately related to networking, like what you mentioned. However, once you are connected, the hotspot or anything else on the network could do other things to find data about you, like an nmap scan.

Comment: Is there any kind of guide for this, or do you have some terms that I can use to google? I have a hard time finding any information about this. The best I could find was a guide that told me to always use HTTPS and if possible VPN if using public wifi.

Comment: VPN in public wifis is a must, otherwise besides listening to non-encrypted communications, even your DNS can be manipulated.

Comment: If I understand it correctly maybe I worry too much and it's not possible for the WiFi router to gain any information about my hardware or OS version as long as my browser or other tools don't give that information via HTTP meta data.

Comment: Your MAC gives information about your hardware for starters, and the OS v can be found through TCP/IP stack fingerprinting.

Comment: That would also mean, that most routers with standard software normally don't gather that information, right? So of course in a public Wifi I need to stay save, but when I visit my friend at home I may not need to worry that his ISP knows that I was there.